# Overview window in basemap viewer in ArcMap hides toolbar and can't be moved

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap

When adding a basemap to ArcMap project an overview window appears that hides the toolbar and can't be moved. How can this window be adjusted or removed?

Comment: By "an overview window" do you mean the Basemap Gallery, or something else?  In any event, I think a screenshot would help for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the basemap along with the Overview Map and tried to reposition it. I think if you need you may try to reset the template for your map document by renaming the Normal.mxt and try to launch Map document which shall create a new template.

> %appdata%\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcMap\Templates\Normal.mxt

[Overview Map position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR6Sl.jpg)

[Overview Map position changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66nHv.jpg)